# Java HTTP cookies not received

Tags: java, python, cookies

So I am trying to receive cookies from a website (https://account.mojang.com/login) using the HttpsUrlConnection in Java, but it does not send the cookies in response. The surprising thing is that libraries such as the Apache HttpClient are able to receive the cookies. Even Python's request library works.

My code:

```
URL obj = new URL("https://account.mojang.com/login");
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Host", "account.mojang.com");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postPARAMS.length()));
    //System.out.println(Integer.toString(postPARAMS.length()));
    //con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0");
    //con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    //con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");

    // For POST only - START
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    os.write(postPARAMS.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    // For POST only - END

    System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + con.getResponseCode());
```

The code above does not receive the cookies. I have confirmed it is working, but cookies are empty. Using the Apache HttpClient, cookies are not empty. The code with Apache is shown below:

```
final HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        final HttpPost loginPost = new HttpPost("https://account.mojang.com/login");
        loginPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36");
        final List<NameValuePair> loginParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        loginParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", email));
        loginParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        loginPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(loginParams));
        client.execute(loginPost);
```

Even Python's request library receives the cookies. I also tested to see sent headers with http://requestmaker.com/, which is able to receive the cookies in headers. Using the same headers as requestmaker.com, I still cannot receive the cookies.

The question is: What do these libraries have that my HttpsUrlConnection does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a CookieHandler:

```
URL obj = new URL("https://account.mojang.com/login");
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager()); //This line was not present before.
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
```